# Microsoft 365 management API, currentStatus returns yesterday "statusTime" field

Tags: office365api, azure-management-api

We're working on migrating to Office365/M365 and when we make an API call to the Microsoft Management API for status, the statusTime field is yesterday.  Any ideas why?

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/(tenant)/ServiceComms/CurrentStatus
```

Here's a partial json from the Exchange Online status:

```
        "Status": "ServiceRestored",
        "StatusDisplayName": "Service restored",
        "StatusTime": "2018-10-01T18:49:36.4528522Z",
        "Workload": "Exchange",
        "WorkloadDisplayName": "Exchange Online"
```

StatusTime is exactly 1 day behind from my current timezone. The time appears to be in UTC but its UTC - 1 day.  I'm confused why? I thought it would be current status.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi BP, did you find a way that can resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you call to the Microsoft Management API for status, you will get a real-time view of current and ongoing service incidents and maintenance events.

If you want to display the current time zone, you could try to switch time zones locally.

The Microsoft Management API will not return your current timezone.

For more information, please review the following link: [Get Current Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#get-current-status)