# Service Communications API Current Status returns wrong date

Tags: office365

When you query the current status using the Service Communications API (e.g. https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenant-guid}/ServiceComms/CurrentStatus ), the StatusTime returned (which should be the current date/time) is always 24 hours out.

This is the current status (for EXO) returned for my tenant this morning:

```
{
            "FeatureStatus": [
                {
                    "FeatureDisplayName": "Sign-in",
                    "FeatureName": "Signin",
                    "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceOperational",
                    "FeatureServiceStatusDisplayName": "Normal service"
                },
                {
                    "FeatureDisplayName": "E-Mail and calendar access",
                    "FeatureName": "Access",
                    "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceDegradation",
                    "FeatureServiceStatusDisplayName": "Service degradation"
                },
                {
                    "FeatureDisplayName": "E-Mail timely delivery",
                    "FeatureName": "Delivery",
                    "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceOperational",
                    "FeatureServiceStatusDisplayName": "Normal service"
                },
                {
                    "FeatureDisplayName": "Management and Provisioning",
                    "FeatureName": "Provisioning",
                    "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceOperational",
                    "FeatureServiceStatusDisplayName": "Normal service"
                },
                {
                    "FeatureDisplayName": "Voice mail",
                    "FeatureName": "UnifiedMessaging",
                    "FeatureServiceStatus": "ServiceOperational",
                    "FeatureServiceStatusDisplayName": "Normal service"
                }
            ],
            "Id": "Exchange",
            "IncidentIds": [
                "EX151178"
            ],
            "Status": "ServiceDegradation",
            "StatusDisplayName": "Service degradation",
            "StatusTime": "2018-11-26T09:58:07.9107187Z",
            "Workload": "Exchange",
            "WorkloadDisplayName": "Exchange Online"
        }
```

As can be seen, the StatusTime shown is "2018-11-26T09:58:07.9107187Z".  However, I made the request today, and the correct StatusTime should be "2018-11-27T09:58:07.9107187Z".

The time is always correct, the date is always 24 hours out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office 365 Service Health Last update is 24 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425506/office-365-service-health-last-update-is-24-hours-ago)

Answer (score 0):

This Statustime is a DateTimeOffset. The DateTimeOffset represents a point in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day, relative to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Although a DateTimeOffset value includes an offset, it is not a fully time zone-aware data structure. While an offset from UTC is one characteristic of a time zone, it does not unambiguously identify a time zone.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615528/microsoft-365-management-api-currentstatus-returns-yesterday-statustime-field) is also encountering the same problem as you, so I think this time is normal time, and there is no abnormality.

Please refer to the following links:

[Office 365 Service Communications API reference (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#get-current-status)

Comment: Sorry, but what you are saying makes absolutely no sense.  The status time returned is a DateTime, not an offset.  If it were an offset, why on earth would the date be yesterday?  I am in UTC, and the time returned is in UTC - and it is incorrect, as it states yesterday.
I should add that everyone that uses the API will encounter this issue, so simply linking to another person reporting the same problem isn't really very helpful (it certainly does not indicate that the value is correct).